# Testdisk not showing drives to copy image to

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

**Shorter version:** I've been using testdisk to recover data from a 120G drive with a number of partitions. When I start testdisk I can see various drives. When I navigate to the partition I want and create image.dd, the only options to copy it are on the 120G drive. No other drive options are available. The question mirrors this one from another forum. https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=1619 . I've RTFM and searched a lot but no joy on an answer.

**More detailed version:** I've been using testdisk to try to recover data from a drive which has Ubuntu 16.04.3 partially installed. It previously had 15.04 installed. The drive is a 120G SSD, which has a number of smaller partitions. Specifically I'm trying to recover the contents of .mozilla which is one of a number of hidden folders which have been overwritten.

I'm booting from a 16.04 persistent Liveusb. When I start testdisk it shows all the avilable drives. These are: the 120G SSD I want to retrieve from, the live usb, a 250G drive and a 2TB portable drive. I can navigate to the relevant partition on the 120G and choose image to create an image.dd of the partition.

However, when I try to locate the 2TB drive as a destination, I can't find it. I can only navigate up the tree to the root of the drive. This appears similar to the issue described here https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=1619 , which does not appear to have been answered fully.

Comment: Try mounting the destination drive in / `sudo mkdir /data && sudo mount portable_drive /data` Then in test disk, when you recover, select /data  See screen shot - http://www.cgsecurity.org/mw/images/Ntfs_undelete_copy.png and http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Undelete_files_from_NTFS_with_TestDisk

Answer (score 0):

In Linux , test disk will not select a drive, it selects a location.

So , mount your target drive in /media , say it is in `/media/data` ...

Select which file(s) to recover

[image: Select files]

Press `c` to copy

Then select a destination

[image: Destination]

Navigate to `/media/data`

Note the ".." option would move up a directory, you may need to select that a few times to get to / , and then select /media and /data

If that fails, bind the data directory in /tmp

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/data
sudo mount --bind /media/data /tmp/data
```

and select data to write to

Comment: Making clear the distinction between drive and location is very helpful. Testdisk lists drives as the option to select from and then offers the option of locations as a destination. As you point out, they are usually mounted in /media, but may need to be mounted again. Very clear and helpful reply. Many thanks.